# How to combine two macros?

Tags: excel, vba

There are two macros that do the same thing - turn links into hyperlinks.

Macro # 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range, ra As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ra = Range([C2], Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cell In ra.Cells
    If Len(cell) Then
    cell.Hyperlinks.Add cell, cell
End If    
Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Macro # 2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range, ra As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ra = Range([F2], Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cell In ra.Cells
    If Len(cell) Then
    cell.Hyperlinks.Add cell, cell
End If    
Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How to combine them?
I need these macros to turn links into hyperlinks in two columns - C and F

The option below doesn't work.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Call Worksheet_Change
    Call Worksheet_Change2
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you want these to run whenever you change any data on the sheet at all?

Comment: @Rory, I am adding links to a table using a UserForm. And I want these links to become clickable automatically - turn into hyperlinks. Without these macro, links are added as text

Comment: My point is that this code processes every used cell in columns F and C whenever you change anything on that sheet, even if none of the cells in F or C have changed. That doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @Rory, In my case it is necessary. Only I need to process two columns - C and F

Comment: I can't imagine that it is, but you can just amend one of them to use: `Set ra = Union(Range([F2], Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), Range([C2], Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))`

Comment: _adding links to a table using a UserForm._ In that case just apply the `Hyperlinks.Add` to the cell where you added the text immediately afterwards.